# Cannot get Oozie ssh-action working

Tags: hadoop, ssh, oozie, public-key-exchange

```
[ashok@sandbox workspace]$ oozie job -oozie http://sandbox:11000/oozie -config /home/ashok/workspace/job.properties -run
job: 0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W
[ashok@sandbox workspace]$ oozie job -oozie http://sandbox:11000/oozie -log 0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W
```

```
    2016-07-08 18:40:34,914  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
    2016-07-08 18:40:34,919  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
    2016-07-08 18:40:34,919  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
    2016-07-08 18:40:35,028  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W
    2016-07-08 18:40:35,028  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@:start:
    2016-07-08 18:40:35,064  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@UploadFiles] Start action [0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@UploadFiles] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
    2016-07-08 18:40:35,069  INFO SshActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@UploadFiles] start() begins
    2016-07-08 18:40:35,071  INFO SshActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@UploadFiles] Attempting to copy ssh base scripts to remote host [ashok@sandbox]
    2016-07-08 18:40:35,426  WARN SshActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@UploadFiles] Error while executing ssh EXECUTION
```

```
    2016-07-08 18:40:35,427  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@UploadFiles] Error starting action [UploadFiles]. ErrorType [NON_TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [AUTH_FAILED], Message [AUTH_FAILED: Not able to perform operation [ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=20 ashok@sandbox  mkdir -p oozie-oozi/0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W/UploadFiles--ssh/ ] | ErrorStream: This is a corporate computer facility. Access must be specifically authorized. Unless you are so authorized, your continued access and any other use may expose you to criminal and/or civil proceedings. Usage may be monitored! Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: AUTH_FAILED: Not able to perform operation [ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=20 ashok@sandbox  mkdir -p oozie-oozi/0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W/UploadFiles--ssh/ ] | ErrorStream: This is a corporate computer facility. Access must be specifically
authorized for business purposes. Unless you are so authorized, your continued access and any other use may expose you to criminal and/or civil proceedings. Usage may be monitored!
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.execute(SshActionExecutor.java:592)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.start(SshActionExecutor.java:206)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not able to perform operation [ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=20 ashok@sandbox  mkdir -p oozie-oozi/0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W/UploadFiles--ssh/ ] | ErrorStream: This is a corporate computer facility. Access must be specifically
authorized for business purposes. Unless you are so authorized, your continued access and any other use may expose you to criminal and/or civil proceedings. Usage may be monitored!
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.executeCommand(SshActionExecutor.java:342)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.setupRemote(SshActionExecutor.java:375)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor$1.call(SshActionExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor$1.call(SshActionExecutor.java:206)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.execute(SshActionExecutor.java:550)
        ... 10 more
```

```
2016-07-08 18:40:35,430  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[sandbox] USER[ashok] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[PerformanceMetric] JOB[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W@UploadFiles] Suspending Workflow Job id=0000000-160708173729940-oozie-oozi-W
```

```
    [ashok@sandbox workspace]$ ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=20 ashok@sandbox

    This is a corporate computer facility. Access must be specifically authorized for business purposes. Unless you are so authorized, your continued access and any other use may expose
you to criminal and/or civil proceedings. Usage may be monitored! 
    Last login: Fri Jul  8 17:42:37 2016 from 10.11.95.69
    ##################################################
    # --- sandbox -  ---
    #
    ##################################################
    ################################################################################
    #                            SANDBOX SERVER                             #
    ################################################################################

    [ashok@sandbox workspace]$
```

```
    To confirm that the issue is not with the public/private key setup, you can see from the above that I have been able to execute the below without any issues.
     ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=20 ashok@sandbox 
    Also, it is under the same user the Oozie workflow request being submitted.  
    However, the workflow is getting to SUSPENDED state due to the password prompting issue.  Any suggestions?
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In case you did not read the documentation carefully, the SSH action is **deprecated**. Just try a Shell action with a `ssh` command inside; it will give you a much better control of your SSH session (e.g. use Private Key authentication).

Comment: Kenster, I was trying to invoke a shell script with oozie ssh-action.  In the process it requires <host>${hostName}</host>.  There it fails to connect when I ran the Oozie job as me (with my login), due to password prompting.  However, I can do a direct SSH to the server and it doesn't prompt me for the password due to public/private key setup.  I was wondering if Oozie runs the job as somebody else, though it gets initiated from my login, however from the log it sounds like it was running with my login.

Comment: Samson, thanks for the note.  I have been able to achieve the requirement with the shell script instead (upload the file from Local file system to HDFS ).